# How to async load pages in ASP.NET 4 while constantly checking for progress?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, .net-4.0, timer

I have an ASP.NET web site, which is currently using .NET Framework 4. I'm programming in C#. No MVC, just plain old web forms.

---

### The problem

Here's the deal: There's a page which may be very intensive (slow to load) depending on the amount of items the user has in this list. (Sort of a wishlist, but certain users have 2000+ itens on it)

The items are products which are sold on the website. These items have different features and prices, and there's a sidebar where you can filter your list. The prices depend on a lot of things, such as the users' utm source/medium/campaign, the sales/promotions that are currently going on, etc, and are calculated on the fly.

On top of that, you can filter by price ranges, and we have a small number right to each filter indicating the quantity of items that belong to it.

Example:

`$200 ~ $400 (130)` - There are 130 items in this price range

---

It's currently working, but the page can be very slow if the user has too many items, since I have to filter and count them all, and calculate their prices. After the 2nd request, it's all very fast due to caching, but some users have already experienced timeouts when loading for the first time, which is a bad thing.

---

### What have I tried

The page itself has 3 user controls:

1. One is the list menu and etc
2. One is the sidebar
3. One is the product list

The same information I need in the list menu, I need in the sidebar, and I also need in the product list. I've decided to load the first page of the product list synchronously, and load the sidebar and the menu after that. The menu has the total count of items: wished and bought.

I can successfully load the remaining information through an UpdatePanel and a Timer. The timer fires at a relatively fast interval, and gets about 100 items. It updates the current state in a HiddenField, which I use in the next request to get the next 100 items, until I get all items, and stop the Timer.

However... when I press F5 and load it again, it makes requests in the same frequency, because the Timer is still there. But as the information is already cached, I wouldn't even need the timer at all.

**I'm looking for a solution that could tell the server to load all records, but serve the page before that... and then the client would poll the server each 2 or 3 seconds, and check what records have been loaded already, and update the sidebar and the menu list accordingly.**

Is there any way to do that? I've checked articles about Async Handlers, SignalR, Comet, but I'm still clueless...

Comment: I would think you could use the exact approach you're currently using, but with just a few tweaks.  Since the timer in your updatepanel is firing right away you can just have it check, in the timer's event handler, to see if the cache is populated.  If it is, populate all of the items, if it's not, populate just the next 100 or whatever.

Comment: Do you know if there is some way I could stream the results instead of polling the server?

Comment: You can, but not easily.  It's not a model that HTTP is designed for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `Tasks` and the `Task Parallel Library (TPL)`.

Upon requesting the page, I create and start a `Task` which filters the items, wait for about ~60 items to complete (to at least create pagination) and delivers the page. Then I cache a reference to the Task for about 15 minutes (sliding expiration). Upon finishing each item, the Task posts a value using a `BroadcastBlock<int>` to change the count, and posts other things related to the filter, which I can use in my page.

The `Task` itself will keep on going, and when I request the page again (through a timer, or a page reload), I'll get its reference through the Cache. Then, I receive all  the information I want through these blocks, and update accordingly.

This way I don't need my users to wait for the process to finish before handling the page, and I can progressively load the page.

However, I learned some things need to be taken account if you're creating threads in an ASP.NET Environment, such as **exception handling** and **AppDomain recycling**.

Here are some links I found regarding these caveats and other information:

[The dangers of implementing recurring background tasks in asp net](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx)

[Concurrency in web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220981/concurrency-in-web-applications/2221106#2221106)

[Performing asynchronous work or tasks in asp.net applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will want a combination of caching and AJAX calls.

You mention caching--are you doing it manually or taking advantage of browser/.NET's built in stuff?

You may want to look at DB-level optimizations.  Indexing and using SQL Management Studio to evaluate query execution plans (which will tell you the most time consuming portions of your query) would be very helpful here.  You could even go so far as to set up aggregate tables representing sums and counts of the data that your users normally sum or count.

I think the caching is about 90% of your work.  Retrieving the data via AJAX won't make it any faster, but it will allow you to do multiple things at once, IF your logic isn't sequential.

I'd investigate what you can do to tune your DB first, and see what gains you can achieve there.

Comment: The reason to use AJAX isn't to make it faster, it's so that the user's page loads and they can see a loading icon and all of the other info on the page, rather than having the entire page not load just because one piece isn't finished.

Comment: @Servy Sure, but if his site is all about displaying data, showing pretty images and a "Loading" vs IE spinning really isn't that much different (I agree that to a user it may be "better", but for us who know what's going on in the background, we know it's not helping them get their work done any faster).  Your point is valid, though.

Comment: You're assuming the only thing that they'll ever want to use is dependent on what they're waiting on.  That may not be a valid assumption to make.

Comment: The point is the user should be able to navigate through the product list whether all items are loaded or not. Usually, even if the user has 2000+ items, he will probably just check one thing or two, and should not carry the burden of waiting for all his items to load just to see one.

Comment: @ConradClark In that case have you thought of paging (at the database level)?  May be a better solution.

Comment: To expand, you'd allow filters to load, then based on those filters, fetch the first 10 or 20 or x items (just less than 2000!) and display them to the user instead of fetching the other items that are less likely to be wanted by the user.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely Hmm yes, I already implement paging, but the filter itself is based on the product list. For example, it'll only show the category "TV" in the side-bar filter if 1 or more products are TVs. I yield return the 10 first items that meet the specified criteria to show on the product list, so it's rather quick. But I still need to load the side bar with all possible filters.

Comment: @ConradClark Understood.  I still think you'll get the best performance (when loading cache) via tuning the DB some.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely Ok, I'll see what I can do db wise, and I'll accept your answer if it solves my problem. Thanks a lot